# How to add range validation for year in flutter

Tags: date, validation, flutter, flutter-dependencies, year2038

I've tried to add year range validation it must be between 1850 to the current year. i've tried but it's not working.

Here is the code I've tried

```
  String validateestablishedyear(String value) {
    var date = new DateTime.now();
    int currentYear = date.year;
    int userinputValue = 0;
    print('currentYear = $currentYear');
    print('input value = $value');
    print('value = ${value is int}');
    print('value = ${value is String}');

    if (value is String && value.length == 0) {
      return "Established Year is Required";
    } else {
      userinputValue = int.parse(value);
    }

    if (userinputValue < 1850 && userinputValue >= currentYear) {
      return "Year must be between 1850 and $currentYear";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your code as below,

```
if (userinputValue < 1850 || userinputValue >= currentYear) {
  return "Year must be between 1850 and $currentYear";
}
```

You're logic is wrong. you should have use **||** instead of **&&**